# Python Created Label - Update Text by ID

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a screen that is generating a BoxLayout and a Label on entry from python based code. The BoxLayout is being inserted into a BoxLayout based on ID that is predefined in the kv file.

I have a function that is being called every second, that I'm wanting to update the generated label. However when doing it, the ID is not able to be found.

Attempting to update the label based on ID fails.

```py
self.ids.generatedLabel = "Updated text"
```

I understand based on the Kivy documentation and other forums that the IDs are generated upon screen build so any dynamically added content will not show up. However, another post seems to point to being able to store the created widget as a reference in Python. How is this done? Or is there a way to simply 'reload' the Screen's widget dictionary after already being loaded?

#### Reference Post

'Since you are creating them in code, you can just save references to them yourself (which is harder to do with .kv).'
[Referencing id of dynamically created widget in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872322/referencing-id-of-dynamically-created-widget-in-kivy)

#### Python Code

```py
    def update_gui_labels(self, *args): 
        self.ids.generatedLabel = "Updated text"
        
        
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        
        if label:
            print("Label found start generating")
            self.build_labels(label)
        else:
            print("No labels")

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_gui_labels, 1)

        
    def build_labels(self, label):

        labelID = StringProperty("generatedLabel")
        
        print("Creating Label: " + label.name)
        print("Label Value: " + label.value)
        print("Update Label ID: " + labelID)
        
        labelHolder = BoxLayout(
            orientation='vertical',
            size_hint_y=None
            )
            labelHolder.bind(minimum_height=labelHolder.setter('height'))

        labelHeader = Label(
            size_hint_y= None,
            height='60sp',
            text=label.name
        )

        updLabel = Label(
            id= generatedLabel,
            size_hint_y= None,
            height='60sp',
            text=label.value
        )
        
        labelHolder.add_widget(labelHeader)
        labelHolder.add_widget(updLabel)
        
        self.ids.screen_Labels.add_widget(labelHolder)
```

#### Kivy Code

```py
<ScreenExample>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: screen_Labels
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't make any attempt to set the id `generatedLabel`, so that's why your attempt to access it fails.

> However, another post seems to point to being able to store the created widget as a reference in Python. How is this done?

This just refers to normal Python variable manipulation. When you write `a = []`, then a is a reference to that list. If you write `b = a` then b is also a reference to that list. If you write `self.the_list = a`, then you've stored a reference to the list in the current object, and can access `self.the_list` later to use it again.

Comment: My apologies. That is a typo on my part trying to build out the question... ```generatedLabel``` should actually be ```labelID```.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect the proper IDs.